# webpack-cil TypeError: compiler.plugin is not a function

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

When I run 'npm run dev' in the terminal ，the error shows.
However when I run 'npm run build', it can run sucessfully.
I think my webpack version is too high to compat the plugin (e.s. uglifyjs-webpack-plugin)
Thanks to every hand that help me.

```
 webpack-dev-server

[webpack-cli] TypeError: compiler.plugin is not a function
    at UglifyJsPlugin.apply
```

And here is mian part of my package.json.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^2.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.2",
    "less": "^3.9.0",
    "less-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.2.1",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.2",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.8",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.1",
    "webpack": "^5.51.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.6.1"
  }
```

the webpack.config.js :

```
mode:'development',
    plugins: [
      // make sure to include the plugin for the magic
      new VueLoaderPlugin(),
      new webpack.BannerPlugin(''),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template:'./index.html'
      }),
      new UglifyJsPlugin()
    ],
    devServer:{
      contentBase:'./dist',
      inline:true
    },
```

Comment: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin needs Webpack v4.0.0. For webpack v5, use https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin